# R003.exe and R002.exe crashes at random times

Tags: windows-xp, crash

I see a popup like this:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

at random times after I switch on my laptop. I usually see it after 3-5 hours. The same can be seen occasionally with another file R002.exe.

I don't know what these files are, but I did a quick search and found that three files

```
R001.exe
R002.exe
R003.exe
```

are seen in `C:\Users\All Users\dtdata`. All of them have the icon

[image: ICON]

The popup is annoying especially when playing games. However, I haven't seen any problems because of it.

What are those files and how do I fix the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)  R003.exe is malware. Also worth noting, Windows XP is long past its end of life and is no longer safe to use.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton , Ok. I followed the steps [here](http://www.freefixer.com/library/file/R003.exe-153151/) and the files are now removed. Thanks. I'm using XP as Win7 is _very_ slow (Win7 takes over 15 mins to boot, opening "my computer" takes 2-3 mins etc) in my old laptop (1 GB ram).